# How to extract special URL address from given text in JQuery1?

Tags: javascript, url

E.g:

The given text with special URL which I want:

> 17.http://www.kt8.com.cn/images/skin/small/url.gifhttp://u.115.com/file/t16785f328#
>   XTM.DVD-HALFCD2.Touch.1985.EP017.mkv
>
> 18.http://www.kt8.com.cn/images/skin/small/url.gifhttp://u.115.com/file/t1c64a6022#
>   XTM.DVD-HALFCD2.Touch.1985.EP018.mkv
>
> 19.http://www.kt8.com.cn/images/skin/small/url.gifhttp://u.115.com/file/t1c1a4047b#

And I want to extract the URL:

```
http://u.115.com/file/t16785f328#
```

And these kind of URL address pattern is:

```
http://u.115.com/file/[fileParameterHere]#
```

So,I need a way to find out the `URL` address I want.

Any suggestions will be great.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Couldnt you use a regex like: `^http://u.115.com/file/[a-zA-z0-9]+#$`

Comment: Thanks for your advise,it seems the right way to make it.I'll try it later!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is probably the best way:

```
var r = new RegExp("^http://u.115.com/file/([^#]+)#");
var x = null;
if(x = r.exec("http://u.115.com/file/t16785f328#")){
   // do something with x
   // x[1] contains "t16785f328"
}
```